Calculating entropy change of system and surrounding in isothermal irreversible process
Let the heat taken in by the system be $q$, which is equal to heat lost by the surroundings. Then entropy change of the system should be:
$$\Delta S_{\text{sys}} = \frac{q}{T}$$ and entropy change of the surroundings should be: $$\Delta S_{\text{surr}} = -\frac{q}{T}$$
But it turns out that it is so only for surrounding and not for system. Why? Where does the system get this extra heat from?

Even though the initial and final states are the same, q for the reversible path is different from q for the irreversible path.

Then why do we calculate entropy of the system taking q to be same as in the reversible process? Isnt this a contradiction

The only we know of to determine the entropy change of a system that has has experienced a process between two thermodynamic equilibrium states is to devise an alternate reversible path between the same two states and calculate the integral of dq/T for that path.  Remember that entropy is a function of state, independent of path.  So the actual irreversible path is irrelevant.

@ChetMiller is -q/t the reversible path way of calculating entropy change of the surrounding?

Then why isn't it for the system , i.e. why cant the entropy change of the system just be p_ext(v2-v1) rather than nRTln(v2/v1)

The surroundings are considered to be using an ideal constant temperature infinite reservoir (or continuous array of constant temperature infinite reservoirs) for which dU=dq_{res} and dS=dq_{res}/T_{res}.

You are aware that dq and dw for a reversible path are not the same for a reversible path as for an irreversible path, right?

Yes i am aware of that

But i am still confused about the 2 questions i asked in the previous comment

Do you think that the change in entropy is the integral of dq/T for both reversible and irreversible paths, or for just reversible paths?

I think it should be so for both

It is not the same for both.  The entropy change is determined by the integral of dq/T only for a reversible path.  If you evaluate the integral of dq/T for an irreversible path, you get a different result.  All reversible paths (there will be an infinite number of these) will give exactly the same value for the integral of dq/T.

Ahhhhhh it clears all the confusion now. On a side note, thanks Chet for being so hellpful I started thermo day before yesterday and found you on almost all the chemistry and physics forums answering thermo questions to newbs. Your answers have been very helpful.

If you haven't read my entropy tutorial yet, here it is:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/
